# keyboard.is_pressed() isn`t working properly

Tags: python

The program works except the keyboard reading, I want when you press escape to end the loop but it ignores it.

I tried keyboard.read_key() too but it has the same issue.

code:

```
 for i in range(0, int(n)):
     pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n') if n == 0:
     while True:
         for i in range(0, int(n)):
             pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n')
         if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
             print("You pressed esc")
             break
```

Comment: `keyboard.is_pressed("esc")`

Comment: @enzo its spamming words but when i press esc or any other key it doesnt end the loop

Comment: Indentation in your code looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `is_pressed()` correctly.

It does not return the *most recent* keypress; it tells you whether a specific key is pressed *right now*.

You have to tell it what key you're looking for:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
```

That function requires an argument -- I don't know how the code worked for you with no arguments.

Comment: It is not the full code, just a part of it and it still doesnt end the loop

Comment: You would have to be pressing the esc key at the exact moment when the if statement runs, because that function only cares if the key is pressed _now_, not if it was pressed a moment ago.

Comment: and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Heres what you probably meant to do:

```
for i in range(0, int(n)):
    if n == 0:
        pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n') 

    while not keyboard.is_pressed("esc"): # replace True with this, exits the loop when 'esc' is pressed
        for i in range(0, int(n)):
            pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n')
    else:
        print("You pressed esc")
```

Comment: somehow it still does not work, i really don`t know what the problem is

Comment: Strange. This code works perfectly fine for me. I set `n=3` and so i had to press 'esc' three time after which it would stop the code. and also, the output had `You pressed esc` 3 times. So that means, whatever the value you take for `n` determines how many times you have to press `esc`. This is  because of the outer `for` loop

Comment: really strange, i tried your answer on a new py file and it has the same problem

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: @YuriKhristich No, i`m using windows

Comment: could you, please, fix indentation in you code?

Comment: @YuriKhristich Im sorry, i dont see any problem with the indentation

Comment: @MuhdMairaj, your code is fine. I meant antique's code in OP, his code is broken.